# Fosuserbundle override event listener

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to override the LastLoginListener to add functionality to it.

I;m trying to do it as described [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/override.html)
It seems

In AppBundle\DependencyInjection\OverrideServiceCompilerPass.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use AppBundle\EventListener\LastLoginListener;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class OverrideServiceCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $definition = $container->getDefinition('"fos_user.security.interactive_login_listener');
        $definition->setClass(LastLoginListener::class);
    }
```

services.yml

```
services:
  app.login_listener:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\LastLoginListener
    arguments: []
    tags:
    - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

The listener itself is copied from the bundle.

The autoloader expected class "AppBundle\DependencyInjection\OverrideServiceCompilerPass" to be defined in file "/vendor/composer/../../src/AppBundle/DependencyInjection/OverrideServiceCompilerPass.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.
in DebugClassLoader.php (line 261)

My goal is to add the ip address of the last login with the listener, but I'll need to create another to add a role and a registration date
I'm trying to do it "the right way" instead of doing something hackish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its much better to use `success_handler` and `failure_handler` services.

```
# app/config/security.yml
firewalls:
    main:
        ...
        form_login:
            ...
            success_handler: authentication_success_handler
            failure_handler: authentication_failure_handler
```

Next you need to register your services and add arguments that fit your needs (probably `@router` and `@doctrine.orm.entity_manager`)

```
# app/config/services.yml
authentication_success_handler:
    class: AppBundle\Handler\AuthenticationSuccessHandler
    arguments: ['@router', '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']

authentication_failure_handler:
    class: AppBundle\Handler\AuthenticationFailureHandler
    arguments: ['@router', '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
```

Then you need to create your services

```
// src/AppBundle/Handler/AuthenticationSuccessHandler.php
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Handler;


use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

class AuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface {

    protected $router;
    private $em;

    public function __construct(Router $router, ObjectManager $em) {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->em = $om;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception) {
        // your code here - creating new object. redirects etc.
    }

}
```

and

```
// src/AppBundle/Handler/AuthenticationFailureHandler.php
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Handler;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

class AuthenticationFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface {

    protected $router;
    private $em;

    public function __construct(Router $router, ObjectManager $em) {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->em = $om;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception) {
        // your code here - creating new object. redirects etc.
    }

}
```

If you want to hook into another FOSUserBundle Controller use [this](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/controller_events.html)

Comment: I'm doing this now with a working event listener, seems a compiler pass to override the service is not needed, I can just  use this to extend the default functionality of the default listener.

Comment: Sorry I cant edit my comment, post hooking it as the solution and I'll accept.